# SELECT on a varchar field that has text and numbers

Tags: mysql

I have a field remote_number, which is Varchar(30).

Most data is a number ranging from 3 to 11 digits long.

When a call is anonymous, this fields value is set to 'anonymous'.

I need to filter data from this field where the value is either >999 OR anonymous.

I can do these queries independently, for example,

```
SELECT * FROM call_history WHERE remote_number>999;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM call_history WHERE remote_number='anonymous';
```

When combining the 2, such as

```
 select * from call_history where (remote_number>999 OR remote_number='anonymous');
```

All data that had anonymous in the remote_number field is truncated due to not being a double.

```
 Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'anonymous'
```

How can I adjust this query so that the 'anonymous' data is not truncated?

Edit:data type[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPTj4.png)

[query ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXDaR.png)
[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFeZq.png)

Comment: So what data type is `remote_number` in the schema

Comment: It is Varchar(30)

Comment: Ok so what version of MySQL are you running

Comment: Version 5.6.39-83.1

Comment: Test `... WHERE remote_number + 0 > 999 OR ...`

Comment: Akina, this is met with the same warning as in my original post

Comment: Please check the datatype of the column and the query text one more time. In current state it cannot produce the described issue. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=aee6d52efc01fb81da2848a8dae6e2c4

Comment: Both work fine .. UNION ALL

Comment: The warning text claims that the server uses floating-point comparing context. According to [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html) the most last convertion rule is used. But if the column's datatype is VARCHAR then the second rule "If both arguments in a comparison operation are strings, they are compared as strings" must be used.

Comment: I added 3 photos, the type of remote_number, the query I ran and the warning created if you wanted to confirm yourself

Comment: And the query you mentioned Akina, I did this and was met with the same error:

SELECT * FROM call_history WHERE remote_number + 0 > 999 OR remote_number='anonymous';

Comment: @stuart we could guess all day or until 3 close votes - you should provide the table defintion and sample data as text which proves your assertion , based on the question as is it's already been proved there is no issue,,

Comment: Well the query wasn't working and I didn't receive an answer that had a working suggestion.

I have since resolved by using this AND (char_length(remote_number)>3 OR remote_number='anonymous'

Answer (score 0):

The reason this does not work, is if we say remote_number>999 we are implying that remote_number is a number but it's clear the returned value is a string not a number.

To fix I specified char length.

```
AND (char_length(remote_number)>3 OR remote_number='anonymous'
```